# Display (Surface Pro 4 ) flickering after / while using Eclipse

Tags: windows, eclipse, compatibility, monitor, surface

My display starts to flicker heavily after / while using eclipse. First i thought this is the common "surface problem", but everything is fine if i don't use eclipse (tested for 3 days.) Just after opening eclipse and using it for 5 mins, the whole screen starts to flicker, making it unable to work with. It flickers in every programm and also on the task manager, even after closing eclipse. It stops if i put the monitor on standby for a couple minutes, then comes back randomly.

Things i work with:

Surface Pro 4,
Windows 10 (current version),
Eclipse Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)

Things i tried:

Using windows compatibility tool,
checking my current drivers (no update found)

Note: I just started programming and digging into IT stuff. So im far from an experienced user and haven't tried any stuff i cant unterstand (yet).

Please help me out, thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Given your constraints, the solution is simple: Don't use Eclipse.

Comment: Unfortunately, thats not an option.